# How can I restore docker data after stopping the container?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Imagine, that have run some Docker container, e.g. `docker run --name mongo mongo`, without any volumes. After that, I've done `docker stop mongo && docker rm mongo`. So, when I will restart the container, it will be "empty".

Can I somehow restore the data, which was in the `mongo` container? I haven't done any `docker volume prune` methods or about that.

Comment: No way, data cannot restore after `dockr rm`, in fact it could not be said as "restart" because when you run `docker run` again, it just setup a new container.

Comment: Thanks @atline :) Just interesting, where docker stores the data for containers without volumes? Somewhere in the `/tmp/...`?

Comment: `/var/lib/docker/containers/$container_id` of host, will be deleted when container deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is **no**. The temporary volumes are stored in the `/var/lib/docker/containers/$container_id` and will be removed after the `docker rm` command